# Timing of mootools periodical animation

Tags: mootools

On my html page I have a few tiles, with a small animation in them, made using mootools. I call them like this:

```
$$('.sliding').each(function (e) {

        var fx = function() {       
            //code
        }

        fx.periodical(5000);

});
```

At this point, all tiles play their animation every 5 seconds; all at once. Now, I want those tiles to animate a bit more random, e.g. not all at the same time.

How do I approach this, noting that the page is dynamic and the number of tiles does vary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set that the timeout will be random:

```
 $$('.sliding').each(function (e) {

    var fx = function() {       
        //code
    }

    //select random number between 1 to 5:
    var rand = Number.random(1, 5); 

    //set it as the timeout
    fx.periodical(rand*1000);

});
```

Comment: Thanks! Figured it would set the same timeout for all items; but test show different :)